# How to post in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

Maybe is a stupid question but I would like to know how to post in a JSON object. I am new in this backend stuff so I am still learning.

Here is my JSON scheme.

```
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    required: 'Email address is required',
    validate: [validateEmail, 'Please enter a valid email']
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  role: {
    type: String
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true
  },
  address: [
    {
      number: {type: String},
      street: {type: String},
      city: {tyle: String},
      county: {type: String},
      postcode: {type: String}
    }
  ],
```

And here I am making the post.

```
User.findOne({email: email}, function(err, existingUser) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (existingUser) {return res.status(422).json({error: "Email taken"})}
    var user = new User({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      role: role,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      phone: phone,
      number: number,
      street: street,
      city: city,
      county: county,
      postcode: postcode
    });
```

So everything is posting apart of address strings. In DB I can see only `"address" : []`

Here is my signUp function

```
exports.signup = function(req, res, next) {
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var role = req.body.role;
  var firstName = req.body.firstName;
  var lastName = req.body.lastName;
  var phone = req.body.phone;
  var number = req.body.number;
  var street = req.body.street;
  var city = req.body.city;
  var county = req.body.county;
  var postcode = req.body.postcode;
  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(422).json({error: "You must provide an email and password"});
  }
```

Comment: You dont add an address to the `new User` ?!

Comment: but if I add address that must be an empty variable? because for example I have `firstName: firstName` but in signUp function it looks like this `var lastName = req.body.lastName;`

Answer (score 2):

You should send the `street`, `city`, `country` and `postcode` in address key as you are expecting these under `address` like this:

```
User.findOne({email: email}, function(err, existingUser) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (existingUser) {return res.status(422).json({error: "Email taken"})}
    var user = new User({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      role: role,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      phone: phone,
      number: number,
      address: [{
        street: street,
        city: city,
        county: county,
        postcode: postcode
      }]
});
```

Comment: this is correct but my `"address" : [ ]` is still like this

Comment: Can you verify if you are passing the data into this function corrcetly ?